# How to get Scrollview to work while aligning components to the bottom?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I have a ScrollView Layout and a single Linear Layout as its child.

What I want to do is my TextView and EditText at the bottom of the screen and then have a button below it that lets me scroll to see it.

Looking everywhere, I used fillViewPort in ScrollView so that I could get those two components on the bottom of screen, there should be a button below them but I just can't seem to scroll to it.

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context="com.example.arsalannadeem.updatedpractice.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:contentDescription="@string/removeHighlight"
            android:src="@drawable/download"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:text="@string/DifficultySelect"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <RadioGroup

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <RadioButton
                android:text="@string/easyRadio"
                android:textColor="@color/colorGreen"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <RadioButton
                android:text="@string/mediumRadio"
                android:textColor="@color/colorYellow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <RadioButton
                android:textColor="@color/colorRed"
                android:text="@string/hardRadio"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:id="@+id/questionNumberTextViewAlignment"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                android:text="@string/questionNumberTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/questionNumberTextViewAlignment"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <Button
                android:layout_below="@id/questionNumberTextViewAlignment"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And this is what it currently looks like:

[image: Capture.jpg]

I want to be able to view the last button that should be below the EditText, but I can't seem to scroll to it no matter what.